# Using JSON_EXTRACT in MariaDB trigger

Tags: json, triggers, mariadb

I am trying to create an INSERT trigger in MariaDB that uses JSON_EXTRACT as part of the statement.
I get the error:

> ERROR 1305 (42000) at line 54: FUNCTION NEW.JSON_EXTRACT does not
>   exist.

Looking in the documentation I cannot see if there are any limitations of JSON usage in triggers.

Below is an example showing the problem. As you can see JSON_EXTRACT works fine when selecting.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testdb;

CREATE DATABASE testdb;
USE testdb;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_test;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_works;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;

CREATE TABLE test1 (
    tstamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    sense VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    readings JSON,
    test_level INT,
    CHECK (JSON_VALID(readings))
);

CREATE TABLE test2 (
    sense VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    battery_level INT
);

INSERT INTO test1 (sense, test_level, readings) VALUES ('ST00', 80, '{ "level" : 73 }');
SELECT test_level, JSON_EXTRACT(readings, '$.level') FROM test1;


INSERT INTO test2 (sense) VALUES ('ST00');

DELIMITER #

CREATE TRIGGER trig_works AFTER INSERT ON test1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE test2
       SET battery_level = NEW.test_level
     WHERE sense = NEW.sense;
END;
#
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO test1 (sense, test_level, readings) VALUES ('ST00', 81, '{ "level" : 74 }');
SELECT test_level, JSON_EXTRACT(readings, '$.level') FROM test1;
SELECT * FROM test2;

DELIMITER #

CREATE TRIGGER trig_test AFTER INSERT ON test1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE test2 
       SET battery_level = NEW.JSON_EXTRACT(readings, '$.level')
     WHERE sense = NEW.sense;
END;
#
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO test1 (sense, readings) VALUES ('ST00', '{ "level" : 73 }');

SELECT * FROM test2;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_test;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_works;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;
```

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?  If you're using a very early version, then perhaps not all of the JSON functions were supported then.

Comment: I am using a newer version (output from --version): mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.20-MariaDB. As mentioned JSON_EXTRACT is supported in SELECT, but not in the trigger I am trying to create

Comment: Perhaps the handling should be: `UPDATE test2 SET battery_level = JSON_EXTRACT(NEW.readings, '$.level')`

Comment: @PaulT. correct, this worked for me. I got the syntax wrong. Thanks a lot. Can you post is as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the handling should be: (a minor syntax tweak)

```
UPDATE test2 SET battery_level = JSON_EXTRACT(NEW.readings, '$.level');
```